# OpenCV bird's eye view stitching

Tags: python, opencv

So I am trying to generate a bird's eye view for my college graduation project and I've successfully done:

1. calibrate fish eye cameras and undistort them (I am using four cameras, right, left, front, back)
2. use preceptive transform to generate a bird's eye view for each of the four frames

and now I need to stitch them together, anyone has any idea how to implement this ? I am using python and OpenCv.
I tried using the stitcher class but it did not work:

```
stitcher = cv2.Stitcher.create(cv2.Stitcher_PANORAMA)
(status,result) = stitcher.stitch(warped) # warped is a list containing 4 images 
if (status == cv2.STITCHER_OK):
    print('Panorama Generated')
else:
    print('Panorama Generation Unsuccessful')
```

it's always Unsuccessful

Comment: What is the status value?

Comment: use the same world points for computing the perspective transform, then you only have to use an approproate blending  algorithm like linear cross-blending.

Comment: @Hihikomori the status value is 1

Comment: @Micka thank you for your answer but I did not really understand what you meant, I am kind of new to opencv it would be so so much help if you can explain a little more

Comment: status 1 says that it is not enough images in your list containing 4 images.

Comment: but i want to stitch four images only

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case `cv2.Stitcher` is returning status=1 (`ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS`) because it cannot estimate the transform between images.

Since the BEV images probably look fairly different from the standard images that the stitcher is intended to operate on, you might need to tune various parameters exposed by the class. For example you can try to decrease confidence threshold to some value <1: `stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.0)`.

It would also help if you posted BEV images (i.e. can they be matched at all?).

As an aside: if you transformed images into BEV, then you probably already have camera extrinsics (rotation and translation). That's sufficient to create a shared BEV with a "virtual" camera at the origin.
`Stitcher::stitch` involves quite a number of steps -- feature detection, matching, transform estimation, bundle adjustment, blending. Most of the steps are used to find transformations being images, which you should already know. So using it here is a bit of an overkill.